# When using the a tag or Link from react router dom, Image keeps downloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, prismic.io

I'm using react router 4 and trying to link to an image on my page. When I click the link, the image just downloads instead of opening in a new tab or on the same page. Ideally I'd it to open the image on the same page in the browser.

I'm using prismic which is a headless cms to host the content images so I don't believe i have access to the content header to change it. Is there any way I can force this behavior through react or react-router?

```js
    render(){
      return (
        <Wrapper>
          {landscapeList.map((value, index) => (
            <Link key={index} to={value.src} target="_blank">
              <img key={index} src={value.src} />
            </Link>
            ))}
        </Wrapper>
      );
    }
```

The target blank seems to open a new browser for a moment but then just downloads the image again.

Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Comment: Maybe it works if you just use an ordinary HTML `a` element, because you don't actually need `Link` in this case, due you don't need to manipulate the browser history.

Comment: yeah even using the a link gives me the same issue

Comment: Hmm.. Which headers are sent?

Comment: When i do a get on the link in postman, i get this in the headers section:

Accept-Ranges →bytes
Cache-Control →max-age=315360000
Content-Disposition →010408537a26f8b9e6d29650edabcf9e3e27b523_4_15615502033_o.jpg
Content-Length →257758
Content-Type →image/jpeg

Answer (score 1):

Take out the “_blank” attribute